# Imgur is having problems (Why have my embedded images disappeared?)

Tags: support

I was about to ask why an image I had posted in an [answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/156943/38335) is now missing, but when I tried to attach a screenshot I received the following message:

> Failed to upload image; imgur is rejecting the request.

I have found another [answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/117383/38335) with the same issue, but others (like [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/222639/38335) one) still show images.

So, now my question becomes a notification:

**FYI: imgur is having problems!**

---

Edit:

OK, they're back!

Comment: Thanks, @Oded :)

Answer (score 2):

I noticed that too, they are experiencing issues (because of AWS, amazons servers):
https://help.imgur.com/hc/en-us/articles/115001058186

Comment: Wait! AWS is down?? Can they _do_ that??

Comment: Thanks, by the way. And thanks for the link :)

Comment: Yeah, I know a few other people that use AWS and they aren't as reliable as you'd think.